# Is it possible to access a class property using an index accessor in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I am aware of [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#indexable-types) use case using interfaces, but I would like to use it in a class as following:

```
class Grid {
  private _arr: number[][] = [[19, 27], [33, 4]];

  [i: number, j: number]: number {
    return _arr[i][j];
  };

  // ...
}

const grid = new Grid();
console.log(grid[0, 0]); // prints 19;
```

Comment: Not possible. Why not just have a `get(i, j)` method?

Comment: Just curiosity... True, that would achieve the same result.

Comment: You could do [this](https://tsplay.dev/qWJv5W), which is bizarre and gives you `grid[0][0]`, but `grid[0, 0]` isn't even valid JS syntax so there's no way to support that at all.

Comment: @jcalz it's valid but...useless.

Comment: @VLAZ Oh yeah I guess it's using the [comma (sequence) operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) there: .  I guess I should say "it doesn't mean what you want it to mean" and not "it isn't valid syntax"

Comment: @jcalz I can definitely agree on that.

Answer (score 2):

### Direct answer

**Not possible**

A [property accessor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#bracket_notation) uses one value, you cannot pass two or more.

The code `0, 0` uses a [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) that returns the last value - in this case it's `0` but for any `x, y`, there is no way to know what `x` was:

```js
const x = "whatever";
const y = 7;

const z = (x, y);
//         ^^^^ comma operator

console.log(z); //7
```

So, there is no way to define an accessor that takes two values or pass two values to it. Even a [`Proxy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) with a [`get` trap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy/Proxy/get) will not be able to recover all values that a comma operator had as the comma operator is evaluated *first*, then a property is accessed using the result.

### Possible alternatives

#### Make a method `grid.get(0, 0)`

It's the easiest thing to implement and quite standard across many languages. Just define a getter method:

```js
class Grid {
    private _arr: number[][] = [[19, 27], [33, 4]];

    get(i: number, j: number) {
        return this._arr[i][j];
    }
    // ...
};

const grid = new Grid();
console.log(grid.get(0, 0)); // prints 19;
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=12&pc=1#code/MYGwhgzhAEDiBOBLAJtA3gWAFDV9ADkgG5gAuAptAPpjzwBc0AdgK4C2ARufANoC6-aAF5oPHgEYAnABpoAJgDsfWTwDMq2QBY+fANzZseaAHNypABSJGrTt1kAra+y7wAlOkNG88My3hNoUgALRAgAOho6HkQBez1PXABfBOgAelToMKzsRP0sbGAAeyYIUhMkVBEmcgB3OArzVzyiksKQcjCQQuNzYwqw0wsABlkh1ya0jMJEJlIYKTygA)

#### Enable usage of two property accessors `grid[0][0]`

This is tricky mainly because you can do it in many different ways but it's always a bit hacky. If you enable your object to be callable via indexing that corresponds to the `_arr` property, then you can just use two property accessors *as if* it's a 2D array.

As I said, there are a multitude of ways you can do this. I'll demonstrate via a `Proxy` that has a `get` trap specifically for accessing array indexes - if you try to access an array index, it will fetch directly from `_arr`, otherwise it just forwards the get access to the object as normal:

```js
const isArrayIndex = (prop: PropertyKey): prop is number => {
    const index = Number(prop);
    
    return Number.isNaN(index) === false 
        && Number.isInteger(index) 
        && index >= 0;
}
    

class Grid {
    private _arr: number[][] = [[19, 27], [33, 4]];
    constructor() {
        const handler: ProxyHandler<Grid> = {
            get(target, prop, receiver) {
                if (isArrayIndex(prop)) {
                    return target._arr[prop];
                }
                return Reflect.get(target, prop, receiver);
            }
        }
        return new Proxy(this, handler);
    }

    [i: number]: number[];
  // ...
}
const grid = new Grid();
console.log(grid[0][0]); // prints 19;
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAlhAggJ2QQwJ4EkwBMCmAHjALwwAUADsiJQFwwAKNl+yUGA0vhgJQPVa8CDDABXALYAjNqQB8MAN4BYAFAwNMUJFhw8RUjABykmcioteAbjWaYtzcnxQxyMMdNsAdAiNoj5HoEhLykJGQAZmgANhD49up2mgBkyR7S3gg4UPgA5myB+iEJSSlpQQZyZAAMNqoAvg4aamrA0WgQIgDiyHC4Sk0w1HAAbmg5MAD6aKgM4hnIANoAuiuGi4sAjACcADQwAEwA7Mv7iwDM5-sALMvLdXba0MhiwFAg5qEqiaVPsAAWaDw0TYDGYIEIGAAEkDcCDkAAeHp9BRkb6lUr5KDkKAzLH7QSUfZOYD4UZsL6DDFJOARCgIFDobBFCy0XiUn7UrlOFxuGC45BYrzTVCLQn3KlcjSNTlSjQ81zuABK+AiILeXixOLxzgJLGJ+FJ5OQ1klpRl1ItGIVfLA+AA7kwaJCcf8EPtAcCKQ9NDLBos4HNPMhlkGFisfQB6SMwLxxtQyv4wXK9fpkO2O5G4cim1RPEAgrzREC5cgpvqLaqrKvWGDRoa9MBQEQ7OpAA)